# Expansion of two Gamma function

Tags: taylor-expansion, gamma-function

I would like to expand

$$
\frac{\Gamma[\theta]}{\Gamma[1-\theta]}
$$

up to order $\mathcal{O}(\theta)$.

Now, it's clear, that we just have to expand both parts of the fraction independently and compare the terms.

$$
\Gamma[\theta]=\frac{1}{\theta}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \theta+\mathcal{O}\left(\theta^2\right)~.
$$

$$
\Gamma[1-\theta]=1+\gamma  \theta+\mathcal{O}\left(\theta^2\right)
$$

However, in my source I have the following result, which doesn't makes sense to me. According to it, the fraction would be

$$
\frac{\Gamma[\theta]}{\Gamma[1-\theta]}=\frac{1}{\theta}\left(1-2 \gamma \theta+2 \gamma^{2} \theta^{2}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left[\theta^{2}\right]~.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take one more term
$$\Gamma[\theta]=\frac{1}{\theta }-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \theta
   +\frac{1}{6} \theta ^2 \left(-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}+\psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)+O\left(\theta ^3\right)$$
$$\Gamma[1-\theta]=1+\gamma  \theta +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \theta
   ^2+O\left(\theta ^3\right)$$

Now, using long division
$$\frac{\Gamma[\theta]}{\Gamma[1-\theta]}=\frac 1 \theta\Big[1-2 \gamma  \theta +2 \gamma ^2 \theta ^2+O\left(\theta ^3\right)\Big]$$ which is your formula.